# How to make a simple daylight on-off switch?

Tags: sensor, light

I have a project planned where I want for some LEDs to turn on when it's dark and turn off when it's light. I have some transistors, diodes, and a photoresistor(and of course other basic components). The photoresistor has lower resistance when in daylight though. How do I 'NOT' this so that I can turn something on when it's night instead of daylight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

evil mad scientist did a great write up on LED throwies, should give you a good place to start  http://www.evilmadscientist.com/article.php/nightlight

Answer (score 3):

If you use the photoresistor in a voltage divider (i assume you know what that is) to supply the base current of the transistor, you can achieve your aim. When the resistance of the photoresistor is lower (daytime), more base current flows to the transistor and turns it 'on' (it's best to use a variable resistor for the second part of the voltage divider).

if you look at the below image, when enough current (controlled by both resistors) flows at point A, the transistor will turn on and drive whatever load you put on it.

[image]

Comment: Well, it won't go from off to on, it will go from probably off to more and more on, in a linear fashion. You'll need a comparator or trigger circuit to have a digital switching action - this one uses an op-amp: http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/sensor2.htm and this one uses two transistors: http://www.electronickits.com/kit/complete/elec/ck1602.pdf but this one can suffer from problems if the light levels change slowly (see the text). The op-amp circuit is a classic implementation.

Comment: I knew that this was the way to make it turn "on" in the daylight. I'm asking how to get it to turn off in the daylight and on at night

Comment: @Earlz my bad. like endolith says, swap the variable and photo resistors to achieve your aim. you might want to get a little theory on how transistors work, too (no offense intended). have fun

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you're going to take the output of the photoresistor and convert it into a logic high or logic low, which turns your light on or off.  If you need to flip this, one simple way is to take the digital output (assuming you are using a comparator) and pass it through an inverter, like a 74LS04 or equivalent.

Comment: Just flip the sensor and pull resistor to get the opposite level.  No need for an extra IC.

Comment: good point.  :)  But if it's a photoresistor, isn't it just a matter of where you put it in the voltage divider?  You wouldn't actually pull one of the resistors, would you?

Answer (score 0):

Funny you should ask .... I just finished building one of these circuits for myself.

I wanted a circuit that would do what you asked for but I also did not want things like car headlights turning it off for a while as they passed by, or having a passing cloud going by turn it on during the daytime.

My solution was to use a 555 timer chip and put the photosensor (I used a phototransistor but a photoresistor will work too) as part of the timing resistance.

I was going to post the circuit diagram but they only let you attach images here if they are already on a web page somewhere.

Anyway, I'll try to describe it.

On the 555 timer you tie the Trigger and Threshold pins (pins 2 and 6) together and from those pins put a 100 microfarad capacitor to the negative side of the DC power supply. Also from those pins tie a variable resistor (I used 250k) to a fixed resistor (I used 50k) to the negative side of the power supply. Tie your photoresistor from the positive side of the power supply to the wiper on the variable resistor.  That way the variable resistor will change both the charge time and the sensitivity to light.

The output comes off of pin 3 of the 555 which can drive a 5 volt relay, or it can drive a transistor, or in my case I wanted to control a light that runs 120 volts AC so I had the 555 output drive the LED inside of an optotriac (a MOC3021) and then the optotriac drives a larger triac (a BT136-60) that can handle up to 5 amps.

Since a 555 can run on any voltage from 5 volts up to 15 volts I used a 12 volt DC power supply to power my circuit.  But you can use any voltage within that range.

Also since I used a phototransistor but you are using a photoresistor it is virtually certain that you will have to adjust the resistor values to suit the range of your photoresistor.

The cost of the parts in the light sensor were $1.22 for everything except the 12 volt power supply.  The power supply cost me $5.60

I really wish I could have uploaded a PDF of the circuit diagram.